# how to avoid invalid characters ? JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, encoding

I have a sql server database that has fields with this encoding: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

In my REST service the characters `í` appear as `?`

To solve this I used this code:

```java
byte array[] = jReqNomeConvencao.getBytes("Windows-1252");
String novaString = new String(array, "UTF-8");
```

but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: If the character in the database is `?`, then the original character has already been lost. You need to fix the code that inserted the record.

Answer (score -1):

The second parameter of the String constructor defines the encoding of the byte array. Therefore you have to use the same charset name also in the second statement. While Windows-1252 is based on Latin 1 it is not the same charset. For your conversion it should actually not make any difference, nevertheless i suggest to use ISO_8859_1 instead which represents Latin 1:

```
byte array[] = jReqNomeConvencao.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
String novaString = new String(array, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```